# Primefaces Dynamic Columns - how to set ID?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable with dynamic columns:

```
<p:columns value="#{dashboardEditionBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{deviceMock[column.property]}" filterBy="#{deviceMock[column.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{deviceMock[column.property]}" />
</p:columns>
```

I wonder if there is a way to set ID of each column? I need this so I can retrieve the column ID at the backing bean. I know that PrimeFaces generate some ID's for these columns and add the column index to them, but since I want to be able to reorder these columns and store the changes I need some more descriptive information at the backing bean (custom ID or something else).

Comment: Do you know the answer now?